# RewriteRule doesn't do anything

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using the current set of re-write rules in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule lessons/(.*)$ page.php?url=$1
```

It works fine. Now I have some old pages which I would like to redirect to new pages. I do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule lessons/(.*)$ page.php?url=$1

RewriteRule old/this_url/(.*)$ lessons/to_this_url/and_this_url
```

But when I go to `www.mywebsite.com/old/this_url/another_path` it simply doesn't do anything?

I tested the rule in a re-write test program and it worked. The rule was recognised. So not sure, what I am doing wrong on the live website?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. In fact I realized a bit late that what I was trying to do was redirecting the content of an old website to a new website. They live under the same domain name but don't live under the same root. One lives under / (the current one) and the old one lives under /old/. So the rules needed to be added to the .htaccess of the old website. In:

www.root.com/old/.htaccess (THIS IS CORRECT)

While I was trying to edit them in:

www.root.com/.htaccess (NO)

That solves my problem.